# Set conditional on first array only in Multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-3

I need help for showing result in multidimensional array.

On first array I want to show 8 results, then And next result I want to display 4 items

Here's my code :

```
foreach ($collection as $co) {
        
        $value = 8;
        
        $items[] = $this->ProductModel->Products($co->id, $value, 'product_date');
    }
```

The result I expected, $value on first array is 8, but the others is 4.
How to make conditions for $value?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your `$collection` is a plain list:

```
foreach ($collection as $i => $co) {
        
        $value = ( $i ? 4 : 8 );
        
        $items[] = $this->ProductModel->Products($co->id, $value, 'product_date');
}
```